# Unexpected token ) in javascriptscript

Tags: javascript, token, uncaught-exception

I'm trying to understand why the error in the title occurs in my script. I tried to match every bracket in sublime and it seems fine.

Here is the code

```
<script>

window.onload = function(){
var socket = io.connect("http://localhost:1337");
socket.on("drawn_complete",function(data){
    imgData = ctx.getImageData(data.width, data.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < data.raw.length) {
        imgData.data[i] = data.raw[i];
    }
ctx.putImageData(imgData, 0, 0);
});


var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var moving = false;
console.log(c);
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
c.onmousedown = function(evt){
moving = true
};
c.onmousemove = function(evt){
    if(moving == true)
    {
        console.log("holding and moving");

        var x = evt.clientX - rect.left;
        var y = evt.clientY - rect.top;
        console.log("X: " + x + " Y: " + y);
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
        canvasData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,200,100)
        myData = {
        height : canvasData.height,
        width : canvasData.width,
        raw : canvasData.data
};
socket.emit("drawing",{"image": myData});

    }
};
c.onmouseup = function(evt){
    moving = false;
};
};

</script>
```

Am I missing a ")" or a "}" ?
Might this error be thrown in my nodejs? If so shouldn't my console which runs nodejs stop? The console doesn't log any error nor does it stop.

Comment: Random indentation doesn't help... Being a little more caring for your code would prevent those errors.

Comment: @dystroy While I agree on the indentation, the error here wouldn't have been prevented even if it were properly indented, since it's an inline problem ;)

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Right. But when you prevent 95% of those errors with proper care, you know where to look...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: Guess we'll never know. Properly indented the code becomes easier to read, and inline issues as well as others are easier to spot. Only sayin' =). (Now let's make this a HUGE debate)

Comment: Ah, but define "proper indentation" :p For that matter, where should spaces go inline? Personally, I write `for( i=0; i<l; i++)`, `if( blah)` and other things, although that's mostly a leftover habit from programming in plain old Notepad which had really bad keyboard navigation.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I would say consistency is first rule of proper formatting. Use one pattern and stick with throughout the project. Rule one of indentation would be: *clearly show where a block starts and ends.* Other rules would be somewhat a cause of preferences with having in mind that other's might have to read your code one day. Personally I use a modified version of [Linux kernel coding style](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle). But that is perhaps because I have written more C then Javascript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.raw.length) {
```

You're missing the increment part (`i++`) for this `for` loop.

Comment: Oh god how could I miss that

Answer (score -1):

on line no 5:

```
for (var i = 0; i < data.raw.length; i++){
imgData.data[i] = data.raw[i];
}
```

you forgot to increment `i++`

Comment: Why add a duplicate answer five minutes after it was answered ?

Comment: @dystroy- more specific answer, I have also given the solution :)